# What would be the C# equivalent for this Java line?

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin.android

I am trying to find a way to detect the night mode using **Xamarin native**. I found this **Java** solution but I wonder what would be the **C#** equivalent for this line of Java

```
int nightModeFlags =
    getContext().getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode &
    Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if just want to transfer it to C# , you can do as follow :

```
var uiModeFlags1 = Android.App.Application.Context.Resources.Configuration.UiMode & UiMode.NightMask;
```

By the way , the duplicate link shared a Nuget Package to do that .

Installing **Plugin.CurrentActivity** Nuget Package .

```
using Plugin.CurrentActivity;

var uiModeFlags = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.AppContext.Resources.Configuration.UiMode & UiMode.NightMask;
```